# Excel: Sum of Range Based on Lookup

Tags: excel

I need to find the sum of a range with a specified number of rows based on multi-criteria lookup.

```
INDEX(A1:P241,MATCH(($S$2*12),$A$1:$A$241,0),MATCH($U$2,$A$1:$P$1,0))
```

The above formula is where I define my criteria - basically returns the value of the "starting point." Let's say the cell reference is P13.

From here, I need to find the sum of the number of rows as defined in cell T2 - 24 rows. In this example, I need sum of P14:P37

Data layout:

```
A1:P241 is my lookup table
S2 first condition - lookup corresponds to column A
U2 second condition- lookup corresponds to row 1
T2 number of rows that need to be summed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OFFSET` will work:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(INDEX(A1:P241,MATCH($S$1*12,$A$1:$A$241,0),MATCH($U$1,$A$1:$P$1,0)),1,0,$T$1))
```